# Shifting values of numpy array withing specific range for clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to shift the values of synthetic data generated by the Scikit-learn package. The data and plot:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=12000, centers=3, n_features=2, random_state=0)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to shift the values of each cluster to make them more separated (more distant clusters). So I tried this:

```
X[np.argwhere((-1<X[:, 0]) & (-3<X[:, 1]) & (X[:, 1]<=3)), :] += 10_000

X[np.argwhere((-6<X[:, 0]) & (X[:, 0]<0) & (-1<X[:, 1]) & (X[:, 1]<=7)), :] += 20_000

X[np.argwhere((-2<X[:, 0]) & (X[:, 0]<5) & (2<X[:, 1]) & (X[:, 1]<=8)), :] += 30_000

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But that isn't what I expected. **My expected output** is something like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

## Additional tests

1. Also, I tried this:

```
X[np.where(y==0), :] += 10_000
X[np.where(y==1), :] += 20_000
X[np.where(y==2), :] += 30_000

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.show()
```

Still, this isn't what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

2. And using random normal dist numbers:

```
X[np.where(y==0), :] += np.random.normal(10_000, 10_000, len(np.where(y==0)))
X[np.where(y==1), :] += np.random.normal(15_000, 10_000, len(np.where(y==1)))
X[np.where(y==2), :] += np.random.normal(20_000, 10_000, len(np.where(y==2)))

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way:

```
X[np.where(y==0)[0], 0] += np.random.normal(8_000, 4_000, len(np.where(y==0)[0]))
X[np.where(y==0)[0], 1] += np.random.normal(5_000, 4_000, len(np.where(y==0)[0]))

X[np.where(y==1)[0], 0] += np.random.normal(19_000, 3_000, len(np.where(y==1)[0]))
X[np.where(y==1)[0], 1] += np.random.normal(19_000, 3_000, len(np.where(y==1)[0]))

X[np.where(y==2)[0], 0] += np.random.normal(30_000, 3_000, len(np.where(y==2)[0]))
X[np.where(y==2)[0], 1] += np.random.normal(20_000, 3_000, len(np.where(y==2)[0]))
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.show()
```

[image]